# How to move CEDET auto generated ede-projects.el, and srecode-map.el?

Tags: emacs, cedet

What are the variable names that can customize the directory to store CEDET auto generated files, like ede-projects.el and srecode-map.el? By default they are in ~/.emacs.d, but I want to move them to somewhere else. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "ede-projects.el" I've found the next solution placed directly after loading Cedet:

```
(setq ede-project-placeholder-cache-file (concat tmp-dir "ede-projects.el"))
```

where "tmp-dir" is some path you want it be.

The same is for Semantic:

```
(setq semanticdb-default-save-directory (concat tmp-dir ".semanticdb"))
```

And for the "srecode-map.el" I've found nothing better to replace line 48 in "..\cedet\lisp\cedet\srecode\map.el":

```
  (locate-user-emacs-file "srecode-map.el" ".srecode/srecode-map")
```

with

```
  (locate-user-emacs-file (concat tmp-dir "srecode-map.el") ".srecode/srecode-map")
```

I am not definitely sure, but there must be a variable not a hardcoded string.

Comment: If using cedet-devel, srecode-map.el can be moved by setting srecode-map-save-file variable, but it has to be before loading cedet-devel-load.el.

Answer (score 2):

In complement to AdVocem's answer (which is perfectly correct), here is a more or less systematic way to find such variables: use the command `apropos-value`.

This command finds all lisp variables whose value matches a given pattern.
For example in your case:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd>`apropos-value`<kbd>RET</kbd>`ede-projects.el`<kbd>RET</kbd> yields, among other results:

  ```
  [...]
  ----------------
  ede-project-placeholder-cache-file
     "~/.emacs.d/ede-projects.el"

  ----------------
  [...]
  ```
- <kbd>M-x</kbd>`apropos-value`<kbd>RET</kbd>`srecode-map.el`<kbd>RET</kbd> yields nothing interesting: just a bunch of standard variables unrelated to CEDET.

Of course, for this to be effective, all relevant libraries must have been loaded beforehand (otherwise, the variables might not be defined yet).